# Retrieving place will raise error in Facebook event download

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is only one field of difference between the two Facebook Graph Query. One will succeed, oter will fail. Why `place` makes it different? Anyway the error message has no meaning at all.

Using following query: `1105135492844152/events`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Place is most likely pointing to a page.

Comment: Hi! But for other pages `place` returns data, what is wrong here now? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63568478/how-is-that-for-one-page-i-can-get-events-and-for-an-other-page-not